# Do Apple's iMessage Extensions allow: Custom Payment providers and Custom Authentication?

Tags: ios, swift, imessage, applepay, imessage-extension

We would like to port our existing application to iMessage soon.

Our application uses traditional Register / Activate through email, Log-In, then Browse the goods, Make a purchase, pay with your credit card.

We use a reputable payment processor and their tokenization services to process the credit card payment.

My questions are two-fold:

1. Does Apple allow the use of Custom Authentication (Sign up, Activate, Log-in with your own systems)?
2. Does Apple allow the use of Non-Apple Pay payment processing.  Capturing CC information in the iMessage Extension app and tokenizing it using our existing payment provider?

I could not find any information about it.  All documentation for new features largely includes info on things that are newly supported, but they do not like disclosing things that are restricted.

Comment: What is your application? What would it mean to "port it to iMessage"? Keep in mind that iMessage does **not** support chatbots; iMessage apps are integrated into a conversation between two people.

Comment: Our application is a native iOS app that is used to attach personalized videos to e-gift cards.   Porting it would involve redesigning / simplifying some of the UI to be triggered from iMessage directly  (mostly in "Expanded" view).  We want to deliver images, video and links through iMessage.  (By user choosing to do so explicitly - of course).